# How to add a check constraint in sql azure data warehouse?

Tags: azure-sql-data-warehouse

I'd like to add a check constraint to a table in azure **data warehouse**.

I have the below script:

```
alter table [FactTbl_Test] add constraint Ck_Test_id check ([Test_Id] != 'Unknown')
```

This causes the below error:

> Parse error at line: 2, column: 74: Incorrect syntax near 'check'.

Edit:

Also appears to fail with the same error if the constraint is created inside the table declaration.

Comment: What is the datatype for column Test_Id?  Can you post your table definition?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide it's a varchar(64)

Comment: Thank you. I can reproduce your error in SQL data Warehouse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This and constraints in general are currently unsupported in Azure SQL Data Warehouse. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-overview#unsupported-table-features for full list.

If the constraint is not enforced at the source or if you have multiple sources, you can implement during the ETL or ELT process. For small datasets, ETL would probably work better. With large datasets, you're likely to get better performance via ELT-L. As in extract then load to a temp table (heap is fast), perform the check/cleansing then load to the final table.

Comment: It looks like the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints may be wrong. Consensus seems to be that this is not supported.

Comment: Doc is wrong, it is not supported at this time. I'll ping the owners to fix the doc. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of the [`CREATE TABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-azure-sql-data-warehouse#limitations-and-restrictions) syntax for Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not mention `CHECK` constraints at all, nor any other type of constraints except for `NOT NULL` and `DEFAULT` constraints.

I assume that `CHECK` constraints are not supported in this product.

Simple talk article: [Taking Azure SQL Data Warehouse for a Test-Drive](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-data/t-sql-sql-data-warehouse/) by   Robert Sheldon, says it clearly:

> **Working with tables**
>
> When working with the SQL Data Warehouse version of a T-SQL statement, you’ll often find that the syntax is similar to how the statement is implemented in SQL Server or SQL Database. However, the SQL Data Warehouse version of a statement is usually not as extensive and sometimes supports options specific to SQL Data Warehouse, as we saw with the `CREATE DATABASE` statement.
>
> The same can be said of the **`CREATE TABLE` statement**. It does not support many options available to SQL Server or SQL Database, and there are a couple options specific to SQL Data Warehouse. For example, the statement **does not support** primary keys, foreign keys, **check constraints**, unique constraints, unique indexes, computed columns, sparse columns, user-defined data types, indexed views, identities, sequences, triggers, or synonyms. The statement also does not support certain data types, such as geometry, geography, hierarchyid, and so on. At the same time, the `CREATE TABLE` statement provides table options that are unique to SQL Data Warehouse or handled differently from standard T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated this test using an empty table and did not encounter this error.
For confirmation's sake, I would suggest formatting the statement as such:

```
ALTER TABLE [FactTbl_Test]
ADD CONSTRAINT Ck_Test_id CHECK ([Test_Id] != 'Unknown');
```

Let us know if you encounter the same error, and ensure only this statement is ran in your batch.

While unlikely the issue here, remember if `[FactTbl_Test]` already contains a `[Test_Id]` value of `'Unknown'`, the `ADD CONSTRAINT` will fail. You can use the option `WITH NOCHECK` after your table name, which will create the constraint without validating it against the existing data.

Comment: The table is empty. running as the only statement in the batch produces the same error.

Comment: There seems to be mixed opinions on the web about weather Azure Data Warehouse supports check constraints, but glad to hear to does work. Also confirms Microsoft's documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints

Comment: @NeilP At the risk of sounding like a broken record, (1) did breaking the code into two lines and adding a semi-colon make any difference? and (2) can you update the question with the statement exactly as it is being ran, or possibly provide a screenshot of exactly what you're seeing? From both my and SqlWorldWide 's tests, there does not appear to be a problem with the code you posted originally.

Comment: new lines didn't make a difference. It looks like SqlWorldWide may have ran code against a different product.

Comment: Can you confirm you are using SQL Data warehouse and not SQL Database?

Comment: @NeilP I was successful using Azure (Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8) using the following: `CREATE TABLE [FactTbl_Test] ([Test_Id] VARCHAR(64));
ALTER TABLE [FactTbl_Test] ADD CONSTRAINT Ck_Test_id CHECK ([Test_Id] != 'Unknown');`

Comment: @coyte that's SQL Database, I'm asking about SQL Data warehouse.

Comment: "Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.9041.10 Jun 9 2017 03:28:26 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation"

Comment: @NeilP Apologies, oversight on my part. You're absolutely correct, and like the others I do not believe `CHECK` constraints are supported in Azure SQL Data Warehouse; to my knowledge, only `DEFAULT` is.